# Sequelize : setting separate flag causes Unknown column error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My Job post model is this :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const jobPost = sequelize.define('JobPost', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        jobTitle: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: true,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
    });

    jobPost.associate = (models) => {
        jobPost.hasMany(models.JobApplication);
    };
    return jobPost;
};
```

Job Application Model :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const jobApplication = sequelize.define('JobApplication', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
            allowNull: true,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid:true,
    });
    jobApplication.associate = (models) => {
        jobApplication.belongsTo(models.Member, { as: 'applicant' });
        jobApplication.belongsTo(models.JobPost);
    };
    return jobApplication;
};
```

Code to query job posts based on name :

```
const jobPosts = await db.JobPost.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'jobTitle',],
    where: {
        '$JobApplications.firstName$': { 
            [db.Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${firstName}%`, 
        }
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.JobApplication,
            attributes: ['id', 'applicantId', 'firstName'],
        },
    ],
});
```

I got expected output:

```
"jobPosts": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "jobTitle": "Quality Assurance Engineer II",
                "JobApplications": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "applicantId": 5,
                        "firstName": "Shanu"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "jobTitle": "Senior QA Engineer/ QA Engineer",
                "JobApplications": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "applicantId": 6,
                        "firstName": "Anna"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Since the job post can have several job applications and need to use pagination and to improve performance, I set **separate flag** for jobApplication model.

```
const jobPosts = await db.JobPost.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'jobTitle',],
        where: {
            '$JobApplications.firstName$': { 
                [db.Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${firstName}%`, 
            }
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: db.JobApplication,
                attributes: ['id', 'applicantId', 'firstName'],
                separate:true,
            },
        ],
    });
```

I am getting  unknown column error :

```
Error: Unknown column 'JobApplications.firstName' in 'where clause'
       at Packet.asError (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:684:17)
       at Query.execute (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
       at Connection.handlePacket (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:455:32)
       at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:73:18)
       at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/nikhil/project/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:80:31)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
```

Sql Query Output is this :

```
SELECT `JobPost`.`id`, `JobPost`.`jobTitle` FROM `JobPosts` AS `JobPost` WHERE (`JobPost`.`deletedAt` IS NULL AND `JobApplications`.`firstName` LIKE '%n%');
```

Join is not performed since I used separate as expected. Where condition contains invalid query.

But, what is the solution ? If I run without separate flag, it works, but, It will break my pagination and performance.

If I Move, where clause inside jobApplication, the expected output changes. I don't need Job Posts if firstName is not matching.

If firstName  = "Shanu" , output is

```
{
        "jobPosts": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "jobTitle": "Quality Assurance Engineer II",
                "JobApplications": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "applicantId": 5,
                        "firstName": "Shanu"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "jobTitle": "Senior QA Engineer/ QA Engineer",
                "JobApplications": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

I don't need the 2nd object. It is behaving like JobApplication's required is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access column that is not provided in query, since it is separated. When you add separate to included model it looks something like this:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE bar.id IN (SELECT id FROM baz WHERE firstName LIKE 'some string');
```

Just move your where clause to your included model like

```
const jobPosts = await db.JobPost.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'jobTitle',],
        include: [
            {
                model: db.JobApplication,
                attributes: ['id', 'applicantId', 'firstName'],
                where: {
                    firstName: {
                        [db.Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${firstName}%`
                    }
                },
                separate:true,
            },
        ],
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I move where clause, I am getting JobPosts without the firName conditions. Please check last part of the question. Is there any way to get expected output as I mentioned ?